# The name 'FramesPerTrigger' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'VideoReader'

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I have the following code:

```
a = imaqhwinfo;
%[camera_name, camera_id, format] = getCameraInfo(a);


% Capture the video frames using the videoinput function
% You have to replace the resolution & your installed adaptor name.
% vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1);
vid = VideoReader('C:\VHDL Project\VHDL Course\Logtel\Image processing\Sacramento Kings vs Golden State Warriors.mp4')

% Set the properties of the video object
set(vid, 'FramesPerTrigger', Inf);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorspace', 'rgb')
vid.FrameGrabInterval = 5;

%start the video aquisition here
start(vid)

% Set a loop that stop after 100 frames of aquisition
while(vid.FramesAcquired<=200)

    % Get the snapshot of the current frame
    data = getsnapshot(vid);

    % Now to track red objects in real time
    % we have to subtract the red component 
    % from the grayscale image to extract the red components in the image.
    diff_im = imsubtract(data(:,:,1), rgb2gray(data));
    %Use a median filter to filter out noise
    diff_im = medfilt2(diff_im, [3 3]);
    % Convert the resulting grayscale image into a binary image.
    diff_im = im2bw(diff_im,0.18);

    % Remove all those pixels less than 300px
    diff_im = bwareaopen(diff_im,300);

    % Label all the connected components in the image.
    bw = bwlabel(diff_im, 8);

    % Here we do the image blob analysis.
    % We get a set of properties for each labeled region.
    stats = regionprops(bw, 'BoundingBox', 'Centroid');

    % Display the image
    imshow(data)

    hold on

    %This is a loop to bound the red objects in a rectangular box.
    for object = 1:length(stats)
        bb = stats(object).BoundingBox;
        bc = stats(object).Centroid;
        rectangle('Position',bb,'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2)
        plot(bc(1),bc(2), '-m+')
        a=text(bc(1)+15,bc(2), strcat('X: ', num2str(round(bc(1))), '    Y: ', num2str(round(bc(2)))));
        set(a, 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 12, 'Color', 'yellow');
    end

    hold off
end
% Both the loops end here.

% Stop the video aquisition.
stop(vid);

% Flush all the image data stored in the memory buffer.
flushdata(vid);

% Clear all variables
clear all
sprintf('%s','That was all about Image tracking, Guess that was pretty easy :) ')
```

I try to read a MP4 file, run it and find reds objects.
Unfortunately the tool pop up me the following error:

**Error using VideoReader/set**

**The name 'FramesPerTrigger' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'VideoReader'.**

**Error in RedObjectTracking (line 11)**

**set(vid, 'FramesPerTrigger', Inf);**

I would be happy if someone can tell me where my mistake

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you try vid.FramesPerTrigger = Inf instead and see what happens?

Comment: No, can you please write it to me in my code? Thanks

Comment: Your error is at the very beginning when you are setting the video properties, so I am asking you to only run vid = VideoReader('C:\...) and then run set(vid) to list all the parameters that can be set, see if FramesPerTrigger is in the list, then try  vid.FramesPerTrigger = Inf ;

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation for VideoReader](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html) you will see that (as your error says) `FramesPerTrigger` is not listed as a valid property. Based on [more of the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/framespertrigger.html) for `FramesPerTrigger`, it is a property that is only used for video devices in the image acquisition toolbox (similar to the [`videoinput`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/videoinput.html) that you have commented out on the line before. So the line where you attempt to set the `FramesPerTrigger` value shouldn't be there when you're only using a video file input via `VideoReader`.

This also makes sense, as your image acquisition system will have triggers and it is important for MATLAB to know how many frames to grab for each trigger. A video file, on the other hand (which `VideoReader` is intended to handle) has no triggers and the frame information is readily available from the file itself.

It looks, based on your code, that you're trying to simply substitute `VideoReader` in for `videoinput` but this will not work so there are many points throughout your code which will result in errors.